# Laravel Site in Folder of Another Laravel Site .htaccess?

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I'm trying to find the best way to go about this so I'd appreciate any help. I've got a primary Laravel site in my `/var/www/html` folder. This pretty much handles everything but I need to add another project for a specific task and would like to add it under `/var/www/html/wrettin`. At the moment, I don't have anything in the base folder's .htaccess as it is all pretty much handled through the default.conf file of the Apache2 server.

Here is the conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@me
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
<Directory /var/www/html/public/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

What would be the appropriate configuration in order to keep all paths going to the primary application while forcing those that go to the `wrettin` path to be redirected to the new application?

I'd appreciate any and all help! Thanks!